# How to extend the disk space in windows 10?

Tags: linux, windows, extend, disk

I have three operating systems on my PC. Windows 10 and two Linux. I would like to extend one of my linux disk, but I can't. [image: screen of the windows 10 disk manager] There is only 'delete disk' option. I can only extend the "C disk". Could you help me ?

Comment: Sorry, this is a place to ask _programming related questions_. You might want to ask your question over at the SuperUser sister page which deals with general hard and software issues. You can see the link in the footer of this page. Good luck!

Comment: We could get the question moved over to SuperUser if we flag the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gparted is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

you can increase the disk space only if you have free space. To make free space delete any other partitions in windows or gparted(if using linux). once there is free space you can increase disk space by adding that partition to your OS.